# Keep NSTimer going while showing video

Tags: ios, nstimer, avplayer

I know there is a lot of questions about running timer in background, for instance this one : [how to keep running NSTimer when app goes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790547/how-to-keep-running-nstimer-when-app-goes-in-background) , whose answer I will certainly use if I get nothing else, but my problem is not really when the application goes in background (that is, if I understand correctly what that means).

So here it is, I have a view controller with a timer that I use as a countdown, from this view controller it is possible to see videos. I use `AVPlayerViewController` for that part. :

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Therefore I have a `AVPlayerViewController` above the one owning the timer and the timer stops counting until I leave this `AVPlayerViewController`. I would like it to keep down counting, is there a way to do that without writing current time in a file and so on ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you invalidating timer in viewWillDisappear or any such methods ?

Comment: Now I feel stupid, yes I invalidate it in viewWillDisappear. But the thing is that when I come back from the video, it still works, it just didn't change

Comment: Forget my last comment, I also start it in viewWillAppear, so no wonder it works when I come back. Thanks for your help, if you are willing to put your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several reasons for such a behaviour, but a common thing I've noticed (saw several times in my career) is invalidating the timer in the `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` methods and starting it on the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods. If you want to run a timer until the view controller is dismissed, then you should start the timer in the `viewDidLoad` method and invalidate it before you dismiss the view controller (or when you get the desired result, but [never try to invalidate the timer in the dealloc method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971698/correct-way-to-release-nstimer))